# What's the difference between Office365 Planner task and Tasks in Office365 and how to access Tasks with MS Graph

Tags: c#, .net, office365, microsoft-graph-api

[image]I can tell that "Tasks" has integration with Outlook Win32 desktop program, Windows 10 UWP Mail/Calendar apps **as well as this weird Wunderlist make over To-Do UWP app** (which is strangely not integrated with Windows 10 UWP Mail/Calendar apps, just as how tasks is integrated with the Outlook Win32 desktop prorgam). I can see that there is a Microsoft Graph documentation for accessing Planner in Office365, but I cannot see the same documentation about "Tasks":

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/planner_overview

How can I access/create/update/delete tasks in "Tasks", through Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "task" is used by a number of applications. They are not a standalone entity, meaning a Planner Task has no relation to an Outlook Task beyond sharing a name.

- [Microsoft Planner](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/task-management-software) is a project and task management tool for teams/groups. It is accessible via the [Planner app](https://tasks.office.com/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com/en-US/Home/Planner/) as well as Microsoft Graph through the [`/planner`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/planner_overview) endpoint.
- Outlook Tasks are task items stored in Outlook/Exchange. These are accessible via any Outlook for Windows, Mac and Web. A Preview/Beta API is available in Microsoft Graph via the [`/outlook/tasks`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/outlooktask) endpoint. While the Graph version is still in Beta, the older [Outlook REST API for Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/task-rest-operations) is a suitable alternative.
- [Microsoft To-Do](https://todo.microsoft.com/) is a new app for interacting with Outlook tasks. It is as an purpose-built Task management alternative to the full Outlook client. It uses the same [Microsoft Graph endpoints as it's API](https://todosupport.helpshift.com/a/microsoft-to-do/?l=en&p=web&s=integrations&f=does-microsoft-to-do-have-a-public-api).

Comment: So does the To-Do app uses Microsoft Graph endpoints or Outlook REST API for Tasks?

Comment: They are technically the same. Microsoft Graph is routing the calls through the same interface as Outlook REST API behind the scenes.

Comment: When are the Outlook tasks that in Graph Beta are expected to be included in the Graph 1.0, any ideas, because we are using them for our application that is to be launched in production sometime soon